# Is this a good way to layout a Web app with a Node backend and a React frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend

My general idea was that I was going to make a RESTful backend and then in my frontend request and render data by backend spits out. Is this generally how to layout a Node and React Web app? I'm new to front ends, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Generally, this is how web apps tend to work these days. The frontend is basically just a user-friendly interface for a REST API. It's handy because it means if you ever want to make another app that accesses the same data (say, a mobile app), you don't have to rewrite all your business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is how your app should be structured. The front end should make the API calls to your node backend and will just display the data to the user. This allows your front end to be very dynamic. If you ever want to expand your application later it will be completely independent of your backend. If you ever plan to expand to different platforms (mobile,etc) you will then be able to build those out as separate "front ends" to interact with the API as well.